# Define branch pattern in TeamCity build finisher trigger

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity, devops, continuous-deployment

I have created deployment pipeline in TeamCity. As of now in the Triggers section I have a trigger on master branch, so that whenever there is a push to git it builds the build. The trigger is defined as;
+:master

I have branches (TC_*), For example; TC_2020.7, TC_2020.8. My question is, I have to define the branch pattern in the Triggers section, How to define it?

+:TC_/*   Is the correct way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We need to define branch pattern filter in triggers section of the build configuration as +:TC_*